# iOS / Swift Fatal Error in withMemoryRebound only in Debug schema

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using my own "ByteBuffer" to dissect certain types from a continuous byte array. It is working fine in Release mode but it produces a fatal error in Debug.

```
private func fromByteArray<T>(_ value: ArraySlice<Byte>, _: T.Type) -> T {
    return value.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: T.self, capacity: 1) {
            return $0.pointee
        }
    }
}
```

The fatal error raises at withMemoryRebound.

```
Swift/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface:23320: Fatal error
2022-10-12 13:26:12.999657+0200 myapp[2298:360997] Swift/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface:23320: Fatal error
```

Right before, the values were:

```
$0  UnsafeBufferPointer<Byte>   4 values (0x282ec4139)
[0] UInt8   200
[1] UInt8   0
[2] UInt8   0
[3] UInt8   0
```

Indeed it has been called with a 4 values arraySlice and UInt32.self as type.

I'm a bit blind without debug mode, so I appreciate any hint.

Comment: A (compiling, self-contained) [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: My guess: The data is not properly *aligned* for the target type.

Comment: What's `T.Type`? How's it defined? TBH memory alignment is probably the cause as it was pointed out before me. 

If `T.Type` is a struct then I'd resort to good old objective-c `struct` marked with `__attribute__((packed))`  and bridge it to Swift.